# titlesec 2.10.1 seems to completely break \section

Tags: texlive, titlesec

Here's my testcase:

```
\documentclass[12pt,english]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\begin{document}
\section{Foo}
\end{document}
```

Using "pdfTeX 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.16 (TeX Live 2015)" and titlesec 2.10.1, this doesn't build:

```
! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again>
                   }
l.5 \section{Foo}
```

It builds if I comment out the `\usepackage` line.

Both build fine in "pdfTeX using libpoppler 3.141592-1.40.3-2.2 (Web2C 7.5.6)" and titlesec 2.6.

What's going on?

Comment: `titlesec` 2.10.1 is buggy and has an update already since 2016/21/03, version 2.10.2 (and what @StevenB.Segletes noted about KOMA and `titlesec` ;-))

Comment: It works for me.  But are you aware of the log warning? Class `scrartcl` Warning: Usage of package titlesec together
 with a KOMA-Script class is not recommended.
    I'd suggest to use the package only
     if you really need it, because it breaks several
        KOMA-Script features, i.e., option `headings' and
    the extended optional argument of the section
           commands.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes: Indeed

Comment: See http://www.komascript.de/titlesec (German).  The new `titlesec` version 2.10.2 does not work with KOMA version 3.19a. You have to install the prerelease of 3.20 from http://www.komascript.de/node/1801. But not that it is not recommended to use `titlesec` together wirh a KOMA-Script class.

Comment: @esdd: I suspect ultimately I'll stop using KOMA-Script and go back to `article`, but for now I'd just like to get my documents building again with a minimum of changes. :) I'm rebuilding my environment to pull down titlesec 2.10.2. Hopefully my KOMA isn't 3.19a.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is broken in 2.10.2 too, but can be resolved by switching to the `article` class. Apparently this is one of those times that a compatibility warning ought to be heeded.

(I was unable to try it against the KOMA-Script 3.20 pre-release.)